# Rails: Redirecting after an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I have an profile model that belong to a user actually when i want to edit my profile i'm redirecting to `http://localhost:3000/1/profile` instead of `http://localhost:3000/profile` why? this is my route for profile `resource :profile`

and this is my profile controller

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = current_user 
    @profile  = @user.profile
  end

  def update

    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profile

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        flash[:notice] = "profile à été mis à jour!"
        format.html { redirect_to @profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Update

this are the profile routes

```
 profile POST                  (/:locale)/profile(.:format)                                profiles#create {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                 new_profile GET                   (/:locale)/profile/new(.:format)                            profiles#new {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                edit_profile GET                   (/:locale)/profile/edit(.:format)                           profiles#edit {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                             GET                   (/:locale)/profile(.:format)                                profiles#show {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                             PATCH                 (/:locale)/profile(.:format)                                profiles#update {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                             PUT                   (/:locale)/profile(.:format)                                profiles#update {:locale=>/en|fr/}
                             DELETE                (/:locale)/profile(.:format)                                profiles#destroy {:locale=>/en|fr/}
```

Comment: Why I'm redirecting to http://localhost:3000/1/profile instead of http://localhost:3000/profile, You have vote down the question even before to read it thank you

Comment: Please post your routes.rb and snippets of the relevant models.

Comment: my route for profile is  resource :profile  and the profile model is belongs_to :user
 
 acts_as_taggable_on :skills
 
 has_many :profile_languages  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile_languages  ......

Comment: Why does the route for profiles#show (line 4 of the snippet) show up under 'edit_profile'? Shouldn't it be on line 1 or 2 under just the 'profile' helper? I think your routes file is more complex and you're not showing us enough of it.

Comment: So because the profiles#show is in the 4 line you think that my routes is complex? all my routes are like this and I'm showing the entire route i could show you the routes file but it would be unnecessary i think but if this can help i will show it

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing a `redirect_to @profile` in your update action. This is one of *Rails Magic* that you will encounter. The convention is, whenever you use an object in a `redirect_to`, it will automatically redirect you to the objects `show` page.

Comment: so are suggesting to use profile_path  instead because i have try it and it give the same result

Comment: how about posting the result of your routes. Run this in your command line `rake routes`

Comment: Just to be sure, if we're on the same page, your problem is, when you try and *save* your edits, you are redirected to `/profile/1` right?

Comment: No I'm redirected to /1/profile/ and not /profile/1 but what I want is to be redirected to /profile

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to redirect to the @profile object, but rather just profile_path (which is one of your singular resource routes). The action in ProfileController will handle looking up the profile object for the current_user.

Comment: even if I use profile_path I'm redirecting to the same route

Comment: idk, works for me with my home page: resource :home, only: [:show], controller: 'home'. Produces helper home_path that generates /home and gets routed to HomeController#show.

Comment: the problem is when editing the profile I'm not redirected to the show page but what you describe already work for me